# Is it possible to use a Deferred object in order to create a callback after a for loop has completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a for loop which fades in each li, what I want to do is wait until the very last li has fully faded in and then continue with the code similar to a callback but I'm unsure how to achieve this? I was thinking that I could possibly use a Deferred object?

JS

```
  var newArray = [3,2,6,4,0,1,5];
    for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
      var dfd = $.Deferred();
      $(this).eq(newArray[i]).fadeIn(i * 500);
      dfd.resolve();
      //.. continue with callback code??
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us your `newArray`? Also, do you want them to fade in together (lasting different times) or successively?

Comment: I would like these to fade in successively, newArray added above

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/): by passing the Deferreds from all your `fadeIn` calls to it, you can register a callback to be executed only when all of them are done:

```
var deferreds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    var dfd = $(this).eq(newArray[i]).fadeIn(i * 500);
    deferreds.push(dfd);
}
$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() { ... });
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwWJ5/). Note that you can use the return value of `fadeIn` as a `Deferred`.

**Update:** since you want each `fadeIn` to start only **after** the last one ended, [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13516365/520779) might be more appropriate. An alternative (simpler, IMHO) could be:

```
var i = 0;
function f() {
    if ( i < newArray.length ) {
        $(this).eq(newArray[i]).fadeIn(i * 500, f);
        i++;
    } else {
        // Your "done" callback, if any
    }
}
f();
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/d7UZK/). I stuck to your original code (each effect using a different duration), but if you want all them to have the same one, remove the `i *` and just use `500`.

Comment: Better: `i=0` and `if(i<arr.length) $(arr[i++])...`

Comment: Hey what does $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() { ... }); mean specifically the .apply($, deferreds). part?

Comment: @Bergi I agree. That was just for `i * 500` to work (as I said, I stuck to the logic of the original code). `(i++) * 500` is uglier and more confusing IMO.

Comment: @styler calling `fn.apply(x,y)` will call the function `fn` with `x` bound to `this` and `y` as its argument list. This is a JavaScript function, nothing specific to jQuery. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more info. In this case it was necessary, because `when` expected each Deferred as a single argument, and all you had was a list of variable length.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) will be of great help here. Surely, you can get a [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) for every [effect] queue on jQuery instances, and because of that method you could even pass jQuery objects right into [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), but I think a callback chain - and for successive animations you need some chain - can do it easier:

```
function chainedFadeIn($el, order, callback) {
    if (!order.length)
        return callback();
    $el.eq(order.shift()).fadeIn(500, function() {
        chainedFadeIn($el, order, callback); // notice we removed the first element
    }); 
}
chainedFadeIn($(this), [3,2,6,4,0,1,5], function() {
    // do something
});
```

Alternative version with Promises:

```
function getFadeInChain($el, order) {
    if (!order.length)
        return order; // or anything else
    return $el
      .eq(order.shift())
      .fadeIn(500)
      .promise()
      .then(getFadeInChain.bind(null, $el, order));
}
getFadeInChain($(this), [3,2,6,4,0,1,5]).done(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Demos at jsfiddle.net: [callbacks](http://jsfiddle.net/UHT8B/), [Deferred](http://jsfiddle.net/evbHP/1/)